# How to make a comma-separated list with quotes in (GNU) Makefile

Tags: list, makefile, gnu-make

I have a simply Makefile:

```
MARKDOWNS = $(shell find . -type f -name "*.md" ! -name "index.md" ! -name "README.md")
all: list

list:
    echo $(MARKDOWNS)
```

My directory has this `*.md` files:

```
$ ls *.md

foo.md bla.md ra.md
```

So, the Makefile gives me:

```
./foo.md ./bla.md ./ra.md
```

But the desired output were

```
"./foo.md", "./bla.md", "./ra.md"
```

How can I transform `$(MARKDOWNS)` to achive that? I use GNU Make 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the simplest solution but works:

```
MARKDOWNS = $(shell find . -type f -name "*.md" ! -name "index.md" ! -name "README.md" | sed 's/^/"/;s/$$/",/' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/..$$//')
all: list

list:
    echo '$(MARKDOWNS)'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer functions in Makefile